# Does $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\ln{2x}}dx$ diverge or converge?

Tags: calculus

Not really sure how to compare this one. It's clearly undefined in it's lower bound and in $x=\frac{1}{2}$. If $x\in[0,1]$, it follows that

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\ln{2x}}dx\leq\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\ln{2x}}dx=\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{1}{\ln{2x}}dx+\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{1}{\ln{2x}}dx.$$

But this did not make anything easier, since both of the last integrals can't be expressed in elementary functions.

**NOTE:** I'm not allowed to solve this with Taylor's L'Hopitals or anything similar.

Comment: At $0$, the integrand has a limit (namely $0$), that's harmless. The problem is at $x = \frac{1}{2}$. The Cauchy principal value exists, but the integral doesn't exist as a Lebesgue or improper Riemann integral.

Comment: So $\ln(0)$ is harmless? This comment is not of much help since I still can't show that it diverges.

Comment: It would be a bit of an exaggeration to call $\ln 0$ harmless without reservation. That's either undefined or $-\infty$ (at least, those are the only sensible interpretations I can think of right now). But the behaviour of the logarithm near $0$ is pretty harmless in integrals generally, because its magnitude grows so slowly. And if we have it in the denominator, it's even more harmless, since $\lim\limits_{x\downarrow 0} \frac{1}{\ln x} = 0$. So we can extend the integrand continuously to $0$. But at $x = \frac{1}{2}$, the integrand behaves essentially like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}(2x-1)}$. Boom.

Comment: Can you use $\ln (1 - t) > -2t$ for $0 < t < \frac{1}{2}$ and $\ln (1+ t) < t$ for $t > 0$?

Comment: How do you know that it behaves like that?

Comment: @DanielFischer: No :/

Comment: @Parseval I'm afraid that forbidding Taylor expansions or at least the leading term equivalent will prevent you to say anything conclusive. Now we can cheat with inequalities, but they are expansions in disguise.

Comment: I know it because Taylor. Yes, you can't use that, but then what can you use? Without some knowledge about the behaviour of the logarithm near $1$, you cannot show that the integral diverges.

Comment: What is the definition of $\ln$ in use? The inverse of $\exp$ (in that case, which definition of $\exp$ is in use)? $\ln x = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$?

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, remove the logarithm through a suitable substitution, it is rarely a bad idea.
Here, by letting $x=\frac{1}{2}e^t$, we have
$$ I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log(2x)}\,dx =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\log 2}\frac{e^{3t/2}}{t}\,dt $$
and $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{-\log 2}\frac{e^{3t/2}}{t}\,dt $ is a harmless, convergent integral (by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, if you like). The troubling part comes with
$$ \int_{-\log 2}^{\log 2}\frac{e^{3t/2}}{t}\,dt $$
which, strictly speaking, does not exist due to the non-integrable singularity at the origin.
 On the other hand such integral *is* convergent in a regularized sense:
$$\text{PV}\int_{-\log 2}^{\log 2}\frac{e^{3t/2}}{t}\,dt=\int_{0}^{\log 2}\frac{2\sinh\frac{3t}{2}}{t}\,dt\approx\int_{0}^{\log 2}\frac{3t}{t}\,dt=3\log 2 $$
since $\sinh$ is almost linear in a right neighbourhood of the origin (and for a more precise inequality, one may exploit its convexity). So the answer to your question "*is XXX convergent?*" strongly depends on what you mean by *convergent*, which should be clarified, together with the allowed or forbidden tools.

Answer (score 1):

The integral diverges due to the singularity at $x=1/2$ where $\log(2x)=\log(1+2(x-1/2))=2(x-1/2)+O(x-1/2)^2$.

Hence, the integrand behaves like $\frac1{x-1/2}$ locally around $x=1/2$ and the integral fails to exist.

We can define, however, a Cauchy Principal Value integral as

$$PV\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt x}{\log(2x)}\,dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left(\int_0^{1/2-\epsilon}\frac{\sqrt x}{\log(2x)}\,dx+\int_{1/2+\epsilon}^1 \frac{\sqrt x}{\log(2x)}\,dx\right)$$

which does converge.

Comment: Hi, sorry forgot to specify that Taylor's is not allowed here.

Comment: If you don't like Taylor, use the inequalities $$\frac{x-1}{x}\le log(x) \le x-1$$.

Comment: Can't get that inequality to work.

Comment: @parseval We have $$\frac{2(x-1/2)}{2x} \le \log(2x)\le 2(x-1/2) $$And now, for $x>1/2$, $$\frac{\sqrt x}{\log(2x)}\ge \frac{\sqrt x}{2(x-1/2)}$$and for $x<1/2$, $$\frac{(\sqrt x)x}{x-1/2}$$Can you finish now?